# Django Inconsistent Login Behavior

Tags: python, django

I have an app in Django wherein the user logs in and is redirected to a page. I have changed the redirect url for both login and logout in settings.py to ensure redirection happens.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL='/'
```

Below is a small snippet from the server post log-in.

[image: Snippet of the server.]

Notice the two POST behaviour. The first one works accurately with 302 as the response code. If you notice the next POST, it is response code 200. This 200 response code keeps occurring multiple times before I am able to login with response code 302 (that is, login works as expected).

Here is another image that shows the behavior:
[image: 2nd picture]

I am baffled by this behavior. Can someone help me understand why this is happening? Basically, I am expecting 302 behaviour every time for a POST behavior. But it yields 200 instead. Even though there is a clear setting for redirection.

Comment: What is "why happening"? Do you mean status code 400? That is AWS loadbalancer trying to access default healthcheck URL. And looks like index.html not working in your configuration.

Comment: I meant why is 200 for POST happening instead of the expected 302. 302 is the expected behaviour every time a user logs in. 200 is the incorrect behaviour.

Comment: "Why was the question downvoted?" That was not me. But at least, your log screenshots are pretty hard to read. Format your question correctly even if it take a time. Respect other people time too. Second reason: here is no details in your question. That is not reproduceable. I have no idea why it happening in your case. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯